# complex conjugate of exponent

Tags: calculus

I have an expression on the form $(1-c\exp(if(x))^N$, where $c$ is a real, positive constant and $f(x)$ a complex function (very well-behaved, no poles). $N$ is a large positive integer.

I want to find the complex conjugate of this expression. Am I able to do this analytically for some positive $N$?

Comment: If you can write $f=u+iv$ where $u$ and $v$ are real functions, the conjugate should just be $(1-ce^{-iu-v})^N$.